# The cast to value type failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper to project my entities to models.

These are the models I'mm mapping to and from:

```
public partial class Material
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string EAN { get; set; }

    public virtual InventoryLine InventoryLine { get; set; }
}

public partial class InventoryLine
{
    public System.Guid MaterialId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastInspectionDate { get; set; }
    public int TransactionsSinceLastInspection { get; set; }

    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
}

public class InventoryLineViewModel
{
    public string EAN { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal? Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastInspectionDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have this mapping:

```
CreateMap<Material, InventoryLineViewModel>().ForMember(d => d.Price, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.InventoryLine.Price)).ForMember(d => d.Quantity, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.InventoryLine.Quantity)).ForMember(d => d.LastInspectionDate, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.InventoryLine.LastInspectionDate));
```

Whenever I run the this code:

```
Mapper.Initialize(c => { c.AddProfile(new MapperProfile()); });
return context.Material.Include(i => i.InventoryLine).ProjectTo<InventoryLineViewModel>().ToList();
```

I get this error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

How is that possible when all of the types that I am mapping to and from are of the same datatypes? I have even tried making the `Quantity` property a non-nullable in the database and in the view-model. I still get the same error.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: What is the type of the relationship between `Material` and `InventoryLine`? I mean, it's `one-to-one`, but which end is required and which optional. Any fluent configuration?

Comment: @IvanStoev Material is required and InventoryLine is optional. No fluent configuration :-)

Comment: Perhaps a bit off-topic, but I'd recommend `valueinjecter` as your mapper plugin instead, much better than AutoMapper, in my honest opinion.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you may find this worth reading: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that the view model `Price` property type is non nullable, but since the source `InventoryLine` is optional, EF (as suggested in the exception message) needs to be able to store a nullable value when the source is `null`.

You can fix it in two ways:

*(A) Make the view model property nullable:*

```
public class InventoryLineViewModel
{
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
}
```

*(B) Keep the view model and change the mapping as follows:*

```
.ForMember(d => d.Price, o => o.MapFrom(s => ((decimal?)s.InventoryLine.Price) ?? 0))
```

or

```
.ForMember(d => d.Price, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.InventoryLine != null ? s.InventoryLine.Price : 0))
```

Answer (score 6):

.NET 4.0, Nullable has a "GetValueOrDefault()" method.
So if you cast the query to Nullable, then you can end up with the correct Type when complete.
This method will also generate the correct single SQL SELECT SUM query and is faster than other solutions that return the entire recordset to later sum via linq

```
decimal result = ((decimal?)query.Where(w => w.Customer =="ABC").Sum(s =>  (decimal?)s.Amount)).GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably we can use the `?? default`.

Answer (score -3):

Calling `.ToList()` fixed this error for me.

Comment: This is actually a valid solution, although it might require some clarification. The reason for the error message is that when the query returns an empty set, `Sum` acts on a nullable sequence, causing the exception. When calling `ToList()` BEFORE `Sum`, the query transposes into a List object. So if the result is empty, you will get an empty list. And the result of `Sum` will be 0. No exception will be thrown

Comment: @Derorrist, yes agree on that. I do some of my code too.